# Getting Picker data from a particular row

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipickerview

I need to get pickers value from each cell when button in that cell is clicked.Like if i click snooze button in black swan cell i should get the picker value in that cell. i am getting the row detail from

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    int section = indexPath.section;

int row = indexPath.row;
NSLog(@"section: %d / row: %d", section, row);
```

Any help is appreciated. All the cells are custom cells.

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value from the pickerssigning a tag to picker in each cell in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` like

```
pickerView.tag=indexPath.row;
```

and then in the picker delegate you can do something like following

```
 if (pickerView.tag == 1){
//do stuff
}else (pickerView.tag == 2){
//do other stuff
}
```

Even you can use Switch if you want to use here too.

Comment: my tableview is a grouped table how to handle sections while tagging ??

Comment: you can assign tags accordingly say for section one you can have tag1000+index like for section one index one you can set  the tag=1001 and 1002 andso on ....and  for section 2 you can set tag base value 2000 then here section two index one will have the tag 2001 and so on for others

Answer (score 0):

You can `setTag` to your `UIButtons`, with `indexpath.row`, if it has multi-sectioned then you can set your logic as per that, Set your `UIPickerView` With static Tag, which should never equal to button tag, like 999999 Tag for Pickerview.

You can set target by addTarget:action:forControlEvent method to call an instance method of the UIButton like,

```
//You can set it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method
[yourSnoozbuton addTarget:self action:@selector(selectPickerTime:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

In Instance method, you can get picker value like,

```
-(IBAction)selectPickerTime:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSIndexPath *nowIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:nowIndex];
    UIPickerView *pickerview = [cell viewWithTag:999999];
    NSString *str = [timeArray objectAtIndex:[pickerview selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    //if multi sectioned, get button as per logic.
}
```